# \savebox forgets its content across columns inside align

Tags: align, boxes

I want to save part of an equation, which is to appear in a single column in a multicolumn align environment. It works as long as I \usebox inside the same column, otherwise it appears blank. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}}

\newsavebox{\foo}
\begin{document}
\macro{savebox} inside \texttt{align*}, \macro{usebox} in differen column
\begin{align*}
  \savebox{\foo}{bar} \mathrm{foo} &= \usebox{\foo}
\end{align*}

\macro{savebox} inside \texttt{align*}, \macro{usebox} in same column
\begin{align*}
  \savebox{\foo}{bar} \mathrm{foo} = \usebox{\foo}
\end{align*}

\macro{savebox} outside \texttt{align*}
\savebox{\foo}{bar}
\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{foo} &= \usebox{\foo}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The cells in align are groups, so you only save the data locally. Try `\global\sbox{\foo}{bar}`

Comment: @daleif That works actually. Though \global\savebox... doesn't and I don't understand why - I though savebox and sbox were (more or less) aliases...

Comment: @AaylaSecura No, `\savebox` has to look for optional arguments, so it's not as simple as `\sbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all alignment like structures in tex the `&` separated cells form a group so it is as if you had done `{ \savebox{\foo}{bar} }` which will also lose the setting. AMS alignments have the extra complication that they are evaluated twice each time.

So the answer is just don't do that, but if you gave more indication of the actual use case, it would be easier to say what to do instead.

Comment: I see. Well I am writing a whole bunch of equations that need to be in the same align environment, and a few of them need to be typed twice - once inside vphantom, so I can use \left and \right across different columns/cells. So wanted to use a temporary box for them, but since I can't use the box in two different cells, what I did as a workaround was to create \newbox-es for all of them and save the content before I begin the align environment. It's ugly but it works

Comment: @AaylaSecura ugly is good here:-) take care to reset `\displaystyle` that is the default in align but won't be in `\savebox`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "reset" \displaystyle? Savebox typesets in text mode anyway, so I manually enter math mode inside it again, is that wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you use normal TeX primitive constructions for boxes, then there isn't problem with `\global`:

```
\newbox\foo
\begin{align*}
  \global\setbox\foo=\hbox{bar} \mathrm{foo} &= \box\foo
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Yes. It is strange that LaTeX's `\savebox` does not have global scope by default, unlike, for instance, the counter setting commands `\setcounter{...}`, `\stepcounter{...}` etc.

Comment: Note that `\sbox` takes precautions against “color leaking”, so if color is used in the boxed material, `\setbox\foo=\hbox{...}` should not be used.

Comment: Note that we (who are using TeX primitives) know this colorstack problem. And it is nothing more simple than to say `\setbox\foo=\hbox{{...}}` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can “easily” implement the commands `\gsbox` and `\gsavebox` (same syntax as `\sbox` and `\savebox`) as well as a `glrbox` environment in order to perform global assignments to the box bin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\gsavebox[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    {\@gsavepicbox#1}{\@ifnextchar[{\@gsavebox#1}{\gsbox#1}}}%
\long\def\gsbox#1#2{\global\setbox#1\hbox{%
  \color@setgroup#2\color@endgroup}}
\def\@gsavebox#1[#2]{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@igsavebox#1[#2]}{\@igsavebox#1[#2][c]}}
\long\def\@igsavebox#1[#2][#3]#4{%
  \gsbox#1{\@imakebox[#2][#3]{#4}}}
\def\@gsavepicbox#1(#2,#3){%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@igsavepicbox#1(#2,#3)}{\@igsavepicbox#1(#2,#3)[]}}
\long\def\@igsavepicbox#1(#2,#3)[#4]#5{%
  \gsbox#1{\@imakepicbox(#2,#3)[#4]{#5}}}
\def\glrbox#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{%
    \endgroup
    \global\setbox#1\hbox{%
      \begingroup\aftergroup}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
    \@endpefalse
    \color@setgroup
      \ignorespaces}
\let\endglrbox\endlrbox
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}}

\newsavebox{\foo}
\begin{document}

\macro{gsavebox} inside \texttt{align*}, \macro{usebox} in different column
\begin{align*}
  \gsavebox{\foo}{bar} \mathrm{foo} &= \usebox{\foo}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, albeit beyond my knowledge of TeX at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Works inside table columns too. I was ready to open a new question about savebox inside columns of table (it was inside newcommand used only in first column and was loosing in next columns)